# DynamoDB primary key for date range and user id

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm still trying to wrap my head around primary key selection in DynamoDB. My current structure is the following, where **userId** is `HASH` and **sort** is `RANGE`.

| userId | sort | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-18#u2d3-f3d5-s22d-3f52 | ... |
| 1 | 2021-01-08#f1d3-s30x-s22d-w2d3 | ... |
| 2 | 2021-02-21#s2d2-u2d3-230s-3f52 | ... |
| 2 | 2021-02-13#w2d3-e5d5-w2d3-3f52 | ... |
| 1 | 2021-01-19#f2d4-f3d5-s22d-3f52 | ... |
| 1 | 2020-12-13#f3d5-e5d5-s22d-w2d3 | ... |
| 2 | 2020-11-11#e5d5-u2d3-s22d-0j32 | ... |

What I want to achieve is to query all events for a particular user between date A and date B. I have tested a few of solutions that all work, like

- Figure out a closest common `begins_with` for the range I want. If date A is 2019-02-01 and date B is 2021-01-03, then it would be `userId = 1 and begins_with (sort, 20)`, which would return everything from the twenty-first century.
- Loop through all months between date A and date B and do a bunch of small queries like `userId = 1 and begins_with (sort, 2021-01)`, then concat the results afterwards.

They all work but have their drawbacks. I'm also a bit unsure of when I'm just complicating things to the point where a scan might actually be worth it instead. Being able to use `between` would of course be the best option, but I need to put the unique `#guid` at the end of the range key in order to make each primary key unique.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Does between date A and date B (+1 day) not work? It should select those based on byte-order so I'd try that first.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, and so obvious when you hear it. For some reason I assumed the whole key had to be a valid date. Thank you @Maurice!

Comment: :-) - I'm in the process of building a Demo, I'll add an answer in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a little demo app to show how this works.

You can just use the between condition, because it uses byte-order to implement the between condition. The idea is that you use the regular starting date A and convert it to a string as the beginning of the range. Then you add a day to your end, convert it to string and use that as the end.

The script creates this table (it will look different when you run it):

```
PK   | SK
------------------------------------------------------
demo | 2021-02-26#a4d0f5f3-588a-49d9-8eaa-a3e2f9436ade
demo | 2021-02-27#92b9a41b-9fa5-4ee7-8663-7b801192d8dd
demo | 2021-02-28#e5d162ac-3bbf-417a-9ec7-4024410e1b01
demo | 2021-03-01#7752629e-dc8f-47e0-8cb6-5ed219c434b5
demo | 2021-03-02#dd89ca33-965c-4fe1-8bcc-3d5eee5d6874
demo | 2021-03-03#b696a7fc-ba17-47d5-9d19-454c19e9bccc
demo | 2021-03-04#ee30b1ce-3910-4a59-9e62-09f051b0dc72
demo | 2021-03-05#f0e2405f-6ce9-4fcb-a798-394f7a2f9490
demo | 2021-03-06#bcf76e07-7582-4fe3-8ffd-14f450e60120
demo | 2021-03-07#58d01231-a58d-4c23-b1ed-e525ba102b80
```

And when I run this function to select the items between two given dates, it returns the result below:

```py
def select_in_date_range(pk: str, start: datetime, end: datetime):

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)

    start = start.isoformat()[:10]
    end = (end + timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()[:10]

    print(f"Requesting all items starting at {start} and ending before {end}")

    result = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=\
            conditions.Key("PK").eq(pk) & conditions.Key("SK").between(start, end)
    )

    print("Got these items")
    for item in result["Items"]:
        print(f"PK={item['PK']}, SK={item['SK']}")
```

```
Requesting all items starting at 2021-02-27 and ending before 2021-03-04
Got these items
PK=demo, SK=2021-02-27#92b9a41b-9fa5-4ee7-8663-7b801192d8dd
PK=demo, SK=2021-02-28#e5d162ac-3bbf-417a-9ec7-4024410e1b01
PK=demo, SK=2021-03-01#7752629e-dc8f-47e0-8cb6-5ed219c434b5
PK=demo, SK=2021-03-02#dd89ca33-965c-4fe1-8bcc-3d5eee5d6874
PK=demo, SK=2021-03-03#b696a7fc-ba17-47d5-9d19-454c19e9bccc
```

Full script to try it yourself.

```py
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

TABLE_NAME = "sorting-test"

def create_table():
    ddb = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    ddb.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"}, {"AttributeName": "SK", "AttributeType": "S"}],
        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
        KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "KeyType": "HASH"}, {"AttributeName": "SK", "KeyType": "RANGE"}],
        BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST"
    )

def create_sample_data():
    pk = "demo"
    amount_of_events = 10

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)

    start_date = datetime.now()
    increment = timedelta(days=1)

    print("PK   | SK")
    print("------------------------------------------------------")
    for i in range(amount_of_events):
        date = start_date.isoformat()[:10]
        unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        sk = f"{date}#{unique_id}"
        print(f"{pk} | {sk}")

        start_date += increment

        table.put_item(Item={"PK": pk, "SK": sk})

def select_in_date_range(pk: str, start: datetime, end: datetime):

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)

    start = start.isoformat()[:10]
    end = (end + timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()[:10]

    print(f"Requesting all items starting at {start} and ending before {end}")

    result = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=\
            conditions.Key("PK").eq(pk) & conditions.Key("SK").between(start, end)
    )

    print("Got these items")
    for item in result["Items"]:
        print(f"PK={item['PK']}, SK={item['SK']}")

def main():
    pass
    # create_table()
    # create_sample_data()
    start = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
    end = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5)
    select_in_date_range("demo",start, end)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```